# D3.js Canvas Spectrogram - White lines and image stretching

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm using the D3.js library for the first time. For my project I need to read a file and parse some bytes that contains the data for a spectrogram. I have the code that parses the file and then based on three values it plots the spectrogram/histogram/waterfall. These values are:

1. **time** on the y axis
2. **frequency** on the x axis
3. **magnitude/dB** in the z axis.

Currently the spectrogram closely resembles the correct data, but for some reason there's white lines across the image.

I'm using the canvas context function: `void ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);`

Here's a working snippet of my issue.

```js
function Waterfall(id, width, height) {
    // Assume a 50px margin around the waterfall display
    this.margin = 50;

    this.width = width == null ? 400 : width;
    this.height = height == null ? 400 : height;
    this.elementWidth = null;
    this.elementHeight = null;

    this.data = null;

    this.x = null;
    this.y = null;
    this.z = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateViridis);


    this.div = d3.select(id);

    this.canvas = this.div.append("canvas");

    this.svg = this.div.append("svg");
    this.svgGroup = this.svg.append("g");
    this.rectangle = this.svgGroup.append("rect");
    this.xAxis = null;
    this.yAxis = null;
    this.xAxisGroup = this.svgGroup.append("g");
    this.yAxisGroup = this.svgGroup.append("g");
    this.xAxisLabel = this.svgGroup.append("text");
    this.yAxisLabel = this.svgGroup.append("text");
    this.tooltipGroup = this.svgGroup.append("g");
}

// cb = callback
function getData(w, cb) {
    d3.buffer('https://d3-spectrogram.vicgonzalez25.repl.co/data.dat').then((data) => {
        w.data = getSpectrogramData(data, 2);
        if (cb) cb(w);
    })
}

function getSpectrogramData(data, m) {
    let spectrogram_data = [];
    const packet_size = 2069;
    const total_packets = (data.byteLength / packet_size) | 0; 
    let timestamp_now = new Date(Date.now()); 

    /** Calculate the frequencies **/

    let fs = 120e6;
    let nfft = 1024;
    let step_freq = fs / ( nfft * m );

    /** Ranges **/

    let freqRange = [0, step_freq * (512 - 1)];
    let timeRange = [+timestamp_now];
    let dbRange = [0, Math.pow(2, 32) - 1];

    /** Read the histogram data **/

    let slice_offset = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < total_packets; i++) {
        let pkt = data.slice(slice_offset, slice_offset + packet_size);
        let met_seconds_8array = new Uint8Array(pkt.slice(4, 7));
        let met_seconds = (met_seconds_8array[2] << 16) | (met_seconds_8array[1] << 8) | met_seconds_8array[0];

        let histogram_32array = new Uint32Array(pkt.slice(19, 2067));
        timestamp_now.setSeconds(timestamp_now.getSeconds() + met_seconds);

        let histogram_data = []

        for (let i = 0; i < 512; i++) {
            histogram_data.push({
                'freq': step_freq * i,
                'dB': histogram_32array[i]
            });
        }

        spectrogram_data.push({
            'values': histogram_data,
            'dateTime': +timestamp_now
        })

        slice_offset += packet_size;
    }

    timeRange.push(+timestamp_now);

    return {
        'dbRange': dbRange,
        'freqRange': freqRange,
        'freqStep': step_freq,
        'timeRange': timeRange.reverse(),
        'values': spectrogram_data
    };
}

function formatFrequency(n) {
    return d3.format(".3s")(n) + "Hz";
}

function initDisplay(w) {

    let width = w.width - 5,
        height = w.height - 15,
        elementWidth = width - 2 * w.margin,
        elementHeight = height - 2 * w.margin;

    w.elementWidth = elementWidth;
    w.elementHeight = elementHeight;

    w.svg.attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .style("position", "absolute");
    w.svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + w.margin + "," + w.margin + ")");

    w.x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, elementWidth]).interpolate(d3.interpolateRound);
    w.y = d3.scaleTime().range([0, elementHeight]).interpolate(d3.interpolateRound);

    w.pixelHeight = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, 100]).interpolate(d3.interpolateRound);
    w.pixelHeight.domain(w.data.freqRange);

    w.x.domain(w.data.freqRange);
    w.y.domain(w.data.timeRange);
    w.z.domain(w.data.dbRange);

    w.canvas.attr("width", elementWidth)
        .attr("height", elementHeight)
        .style("padding", w.margin + "px")
        .style("position", "absolute");
    w.rectangle.attr("width", elementWidth)
        .attr("height", elementHeight)
        .style("fill", "#fff")
        .style("opacity", 0);

    w.xAxis = d3.axisTop(w.x).ticks(16).tickFormat(formatFrequency);
    w.xAxisGroup.attr("class", "axis x-axis")
        .call(w.xAxis);
    w.yAxis = d3.axisLeft(w.y);
    w.yAxisGroup.attr("class", "axis y-axis")
        .call(w.yAxis);

    w.xAxisLabel.attr("class", "axis x-axis")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + elementWidth / 2 + "," + -w.margin / 2 + ")")
        .text("Frequency");
    w.yAxisLabel.attr("class", "axis y-axis")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + -w.margin / 2 + "," + (w.margin / 4) + ")")
        .text("Time");

    renderDisplay(w);
}

function renderDisplay(w) {
    let context = w.canvas.node().getContext("2d");
    
    let pHeight = Math.ceil(w.elementHeight / w.data.values.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < w.data.values.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < w.data.values[i].values.length; j++) {
            context.fillStyle = w.z(w.data.values[i].values[j].dB);
            context.fillRect(w.x(w.data.values[i].values[j].freq),
                w.y(w.data.values[i].dateTime),
                w.x(w.data.values[i].values[j].freq + w.data.freqStep) - w.x(w.data.values[i].values[j].freq),
                pHeight)
        }
    }
}

var w = new Waterfall("#waterfall", 900, 400);
getData(w, initDisplay);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.16.0/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="waterfall"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a fiddle for anyone who wants it there: https://jsfiddle.net/k0zbhs7d/

And here's a replit: https://replit.com/@vicgonzalez25/d3-spectrogram#index.html

Comment: Wild guesses: are your white lines a function of either `pHeight` being less than you expect; or just missing portions of the time series?

Comment: I've changed the pHeight value to something higher, it does remove the white lines, but kind of stretches the image. Also, why is it that the lower portion, all the 'pixels' are together and towards the top the white lines start to appear? There's 512 data points in a row horizontally and 299 lines vertically (rows)